# How do you scrape json from APIs but from multiple pages? (scrapy)

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to get json user informations from mastodon api https://mastodon.online/api/v1/accounts/1  (user id number). the problem is every page only stores one user info at a time, however I want to collect all the information at once. Is there a way to collect the json files at number order (`https://mastodon.online/api/v1/accounts/{1,2,3,4,...}`) then store it all in one json file?

I've been looking around for answers and everytime I used one that is similar to my question it wouldn't work. if anyone can help it would be really great, I've been stuck all day trying stuff out.

documentation; https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/accounts/#retrieve-information

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @SamsulIslam I modified a few things from https://github.com/canyousayyes/scrapy-web-crawler-by-rest-api like the api_pattern and rules to suit my own case. It's way simpler than what the guy made but I just can't seem to figure. and every guide out there is mostly for html not APIs.

Comment: @SamsulIslam also took examples from other (json) APIs scrapy article and question boards. still always says it scraped (0) information or just flat out didn't work